# Why can't capture data package when linked to external net?

Tags: wordpress, tcp, udp

The wordpress is built on my local pc, tcp packages can be captured with wireshark.
Here is the tcp packages captured when to login my wordpress locally,at the same time external net is down.

[image]
Now to link external net and reboot wireshark,logout wordpress and re-login wordpress again,tcp packages between localhost can't be captured at all ,why?
To input **http.request.method==POST** in filter or **ip.dst==127.0.0.1** or **ip.dst==192.168.1.176** (192.168.1.176 is ip in my home network) get nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To choose interface --loopback:lo,then start it,ok.